# Open new tab after server response with jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a lil problem with opening new tab in the browser after server response. Here is a server code (I use Rails 3.0.5):

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :json => {:url => link.url}, :status => :accepted }
end
```

So since I use jQuery as a default JS library after AJAX call I handle server response with this script:

```
$('.link').bind('ajax:success',
  function(e, data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    $('#megalink').attr("href", data.url);
    $('#megalink').trigger('click');
});
```

where "megalink" is:

```
<a href="" style="color:white;" target="_blank" id="megalink">.</a>
```

So the problem is: After 202 server response new tab isn`t created. May be you know how to open url in the new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.open(data.url);`

Hope that helps.

Comment: window.open just opens new window, not a browser tab and this is an issue

Comment: The problem is that the browser gets to determine how to handle that action.  For me, it opens in a tab (I'm using Firefox).  There is no window.openTab() functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the _blank target should work, if you could setup a jsfiddle to show how it breaks, it'd be easier to help.  Otherwise, you can just try doing:

```
window.open(thenewurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser popup blocker blocks opening a new window during script execution context.

Use jquery AJAX in a synchronous mode it will solve your problem.

Comment: I allow browser to open all popup windows but the problem is still unsolved((