# Rails wicked_pdf open PDF in new tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am able to create a PDF using the wicked_pdf gem for Rails. However it opens immediately in a tab because of setting target="_blank" on the link to generate it, but the data for the PDF takes about 30 seconds to generate. So the users just sit, looking at a blank tab, for that whole time.

I have added a notification window on how the process is going, but its on the original tab. I am trying to figure out a way to not open the new tab, that displays the PDF, until the PDF is finished generating/pulling all the data. I have looked through https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf and haven't come up with a solution, but I can't be the only one that is trying to pull off this feature. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this would be a part of the wicked_pdf gem. Personally, I would suggest using an AJAX call hit an endpoint that generates the pdf. Once that's completed you can open a new window via `window.open()`.  See [Open new tab after server response with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231046/open-new-tab-after-server-response-with-jquery)

Another thing to note, is that usually you'll use something like Sidekiq to schedule a task that takes any appreciable time to run, as you're potentially going to hang up your server while the job is running.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to start using delayed_job because we already use that in a few other places in our system.